# Is there a closed form formula for this product expression?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine the value of the  function $p(\alpha,x)$ for given values of $\alpha$ and $x$, where $0<\alpha<1$ and  $0<x<1$. The function $p(\alpha,x)$ is defined by the expression given below.
$$ 
    p(\alpha,x)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\alpha^{k}x\right).
$$
Is there a closed form expression for this function? Any help towards addressing this question would be appreciated.

Comment: it has a name, [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) --- but no closed form evaluation.

Comment: It has a power simple series expansion in x

Comment: Thank you very much @CarloBeenakker. Your answer has opened my eyes to an interesting new world.

Comment: Thanks @PietroMajer. Can one derive a simply expressible upper bound to the convergence value, in terms of $\alpha$ and $x$,  from the series expansion?

Comment: What you wrote IS a closed expression. What better expression do you hope for?

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreEremenko. What I mean is a  simpler alternative to the product expression or the series expression mentioned by Pietro Majer. Initially when I formulated the function as a solution to a problem that I am solving, I derived it as a series. I had imagined that the series would have a simply expressed limit such as the type one gets for a geometric series. Getting a simply expressed limit to the series proved to be very difficult. Deducing that simple form, that I am seeking, from the above product is equally very difficult. I suppose I have to live with the product expression.